# Replicate tee behaviour without subshell usage so that variable scope is not affected

Tags: bash, tee

I need the capture the output of a command group in BASH to STDOUT and a log file. Consider this code with command grouping and it's output

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

main(){
declare -i mycode=1
echo "Declared mycode:${mycode}"

{
  #command group
  echo "mycode:${mycode}"
  mycode=2
  echo "mycode:${mycode}"
} 2>&1

echo "mycode:${mycode}"
}

main
```

the output is:

```
Declared mycode:1
mycode:1
mycode:2
mycode:2
```

I need to capture the command group output to a log file and STDOUT so I add tee as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

main(){
declare -i mycode=1
echo "Declared mycode:${mycode}"

{
  #command group
  echo "mycode:${mycode}"
  mycode=2
  echo "mycode:${mycode}"
} 2>&1 | tee ~/log.log

 echo "mycode:${mycode}"
}

main
```

but now the output is as follows:

```
Declared mycode:1
mycode:1
mycode:2
mycode:1
```

So value of the *mycode* variable does not get set to 2 in the outer scope when tee is used as the left of tee will be run in a subshell. For various reason I need *mycode* defined in the global scope so I need to avoid subshells.

How can I achieve the behaviour of tee without a subshell whereby I can stream output to STDOUT and a log file.

Answer (score 1):

One way of approaching this is to implement the pipe connector yourself:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialisation
mycode=1

# Tidy up
trap 'ss=$?; [ -n "$tmpd" ] && [ -d "$tmpd" ] && rm -rf "$tmpd"; exit $ss' 1 2 15

# Unique temporary directory
tmpd=$(mktemp --directory "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX")

# Create pipe
pipe="$tmpd/pipe"
mknod "$pipe" p

# Output
tee <"$pipe" "$HOME/log.log" &

# Subprocess
{
    echo "mycode:${mycode}"

    mycode=2
    echo "mycode:${mycode}"

} >"$pipe" 2>&1

# Destroy temporary, including pipe
wait
rm -rf "$tmpd"

# Done
echo "final mycode:${mycode}"
```

Output

```
mycode:1
mycode:2
final mycode:2
```

Also `cat ~/log.log`

```
mycode:1
mycode:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve with the log file you might like to attach it to descriptor #3. (Remember *stdout* is #1 and *stderr* is #3.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initialisation
mycode=1

# Attach fd3 to the logfile and stdout
exec 3> >(tee "$HOME/log.log" >&1)

# Demonstrations
echo this is to stdout
echo this is to stderr >&2
echo this is to logfile and stdout >&3

# Subprocess
{
    echo "mycode:${mycode}"

    mycode=2
    echo "mycode:${mycode}"

} 2>&1 1>&3

# Done
echo "final mycode:${mycode}"
sleep 0.25
```

An advantage of this approach is that it's then very easy to write to the logfile from anywhere simply by redirecting to file descriptor 3 (see the "Demonstrations" block of code, above).

A disadvantage is that the `tee` runs asynchronously and so output may be wrongly interleaved. The `sleep 0.25` at the end aims to allow time for `tee` to finish writing its output. Depending on how you're using the feature the interleaving may or may not be a real world problem.

Example output:

```
this is to stdout
this is to stderr
final mycode:2
this is to logfile and stdout
mycode:1
mycode:2
```

Log file (`cat "$HOME/log.log"`):

```
this is to logfile and stdout
mycode:1
mycode:2
```